# Problema instalación Sass Mac

Tags: css, macos, sass, scss, atom-editor

Intentando instalar Sass en Mac (y usando Atom) me da problemas, como si no existiese instalado Sass.

He seguido los pasos:

1. Instalar node.js (desde su instalador de la web)
2. Actualizar ruby (desde terminal con `$ brew install ruby`)
3. Instalar Sass (desde terminal `$ gem install sass`)

Y luego he instalado en Atom los plugins sass-linter y sass-autocompiler pero en cuanto intento compilar un fichero .scss a .css me salta el error de que no existen los comandos de sass.

Al ejecutar en el terminal `sass -v`me salta la versión que tengo instalada pero es como si Atom no me lo reconociese. ¿Me estoy saltando algún paso?

Comment: a modo de comentario, reiniciaste el Atom para que arrancara con el entorno nuevo en el que `sass` está en el `PATH` no?

Comment: Si @yorodm de ahí que me extrañase, pero ya he encontrado la solución ;)

Answer (score 1):

Después de probar, con lo siguiente me ha funcionado:

1. Quitado los packages `sass-linter y sass-autocompiler` de Atom y cerrado Atom.
2. He iniciado en el terminal como `root`y he ejecutado el comando `npm install node-sass -g` para instalarlo de forma global.
3. He iniciado Atom e instalado de nuevo los paquetes y ha funcionado a la perfección.

Seguramente no se hubiese instalado bien de forma global al primer intento de instalar Sass.

Comment: Interesante, aparentemente cuando abres la terminal algún archivo de inicialización del shell te incluye `$HOME/node_modules/bin` o `$HOME/bin` al `PATH`, por eso funciona desde la terminal pero no cuando abres el programa

Comment: Parece que si..ha sido rehacer la instalación pero como root y ha dejado ejecutarse usando el editor :)