# Compilar SASS en Mac con Big Sur

Tags: macos, sass, atom-editor

Estoy intentando compilar ficheros `.scss` en MAC con Big Sur (con el editor Atom) y no tengo forma...he probado todo tipo de instalaciones (tanto con el usuario administrador como con root) y nada.

Cuando intento compilar un fichero `.scss` siempre me saca por consola que no se encuentra el comando `sass` o `node-sass`.

Los pasos que he hecho son:

1. Instalar homebrew (aquí sin problemas).
2. Instalar Node.js directamente desde su web (sin problemas tampoco).
3. Actualizar/Instalar Ruby `brew install ruby`
4. Instalar Sass `gem install sass`

El editor tiene el plugin `sass-autocompile`.

He probado lo que en su día puse en esta pregunta y me funcionó en su día
[Problema instalación Sass Mac](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50907/problema-instalaci%C3%B3n-sass-mac)

Y nada...tampoco funciona con root y no hay forma.

¿Alguna idea?

Edito: He probado también a instalar el package `atom-sass` y me pasa lo mismo.
He probado a quitar y poner de nuevo los plugins y nada de nada.
Los errores que me dan:

`Command failed: sass "/Users/marcos/Developer/maria/wp-content/themes/igualhablando/style.scss" "/Users/marcos/Developer/maria/wp-content/themes/igualhablando/style.css" Errno::EROFS: Read-only file system @ dir_s_mkdir - ./.sass-cache Use --trace for backtrace.`

Me aparece ese error y otro en la consola:

`/bin/sh: node-sass command not found`

Comment: Hola! Recuerda poner el texto completo del error para que todos tengan más pistas sobre el problema que tienes. De preferencia, ponerlo como texto.

Comment: Puesto @Alfabravo, no se guardó la edición antes. 
No se por qué me aparece que está en `read-only`dicha carpeta...escribo y borro y edito sin problemas. Igual que los comandos...el terminal me devuelve que sass está instalado pero luego no hay forma de encontrar dichos comandos.